# Regex: Replace letters/words in a string (Powershell)

Tags: regex, powershell

I need some helüp regarding regex.

### I have this Input

$input=@("Microsoft Windows Server 2003, Standard Editon", "Microsoft Windows Server 2003 Standard Editon")

### what I want is that Ouput

$input.Replace($pattern,"R2")

Microsoft Windows Server 2003 R2 Standard Editon

Microsoft Windows Server 2003 R2 Standard Editon

#

I do not know how to create the $pattern for this one...

Please can u help me

Kind Regards

Comment: Post what you've tried, and we'll be happy to guide you. If you don't know where to start, I recommend giving this site a shot: http://regexone.com/. It's an interactive tutorial.

Comment: You can't use a regex with the string replace() method.  You need to use the Powersehll -replace operator, or the [regex]::replace() static method.

Comment: If its just this two, your pattern is :                                Microsoft Windows Server 2003(,)* Standard Editon

Answer (score 0):

If you really only want to add an "R2" before all "Standard", try this:

```
,? (?=Standard)
```

I think this matches what you want exactly.

The **(?=Standard)** grabs what is behind "Standard".

Try an online regex tester, like [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com) to testout your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
   @("Microsoft Windows Server 2003, Standard Editon", "Microsoft Windows Server 2003 Standard Editon") | % {$_ -replace "\d+", "2003 R2"}
```